# Instagram API, /media/recent shows only images from current year?

Tags: javascript, image, api, instagram

This query:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent/?client_id=...
```

Worked a week ago (end of 2013). Now it shows just 1 image. The only image that has been uploaded with the tag-name I am trying to show. I cannot find any documentation on it. Can it really be true that I am unable to see any earlier images, when showing images with a certain tag-name?

I find the API a bit beta. When querying for 20 images, I perhaps only get 16 or 19 images. According to users on SO, the reason is that Instagram finds the images in their database, but removes those that come from a profile which is private, before sending the JSON. Giving us developers more of a headache, to maintain a stable stream of images.

Edit 1:
I've tried tagging some older pictures and they are now included in the JSON as well. But the > 200 pictures, which were tagged last year, still isn't showing. This is so weird.

Edit: 2:
The tag that isn't working, is #aarhusteater (http://statigr.am/viewer.php#/tag/aarhusteater/).
Other tags seems to be working fine. Have now added a bug-request to Instagram.

Comment: I dont think tags are limited to current year, something specific to that tag, are all other missing pictures with the tag public?, I checked this tag and I can see pics from 2 years ago: http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/tags#uefa2012

Comment: Yes, most of the other images are public - Instagram has responded though, saying it's an error in the API. You're right that the error seemed specific to my tag, some very weird behavoir.

Comment: Yes, I saw this post: http://developers.instagram.com/post/72497508869/platform-issues-with-hashtags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instagram responded to the bug enquiry and confirmed there's an issue with hashtags on the endpoint API.

http://developers.instagram.com/post/72497508869/platform-issues-with-hashtags

Nothing more to do than wait for a fix - thanks for the input guys :)

Comment: The bug has been fixed, my request are now returning the correct number of images.

Answer (score 1):

> Now it shows just 1 image. The only image that has been uploaded with
>   the tag-name I am trying to show. I cannot find any documentation on
>   it. Can it really be true that I am unable to see any earlier images,
>   when showing images with a certain tag-name?

Tag API results are [completely erratic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/instagram-api-developers/R_-0lfzsFyI), largely based on server load, Instagram's API configuration (which they often change without notice), whether the results are from private users, and/or whether the photo has been deleted.

> I find the API a bit beta. When querying for 20 images, I perhaps only
>   get 16 or 19 images.

This is often due to private results being filtered out, same reference as above.

> Other tags seems to be working fine. Have now added a bug-request to
>   Instagram.

This is the appropriate action ;)

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspecions regarding the erratic API. I have stoppped recommending the usage of Instagram endpoints to customers while the API is in it's current state.

Answer (score 0):

I too notice similar problems on my app. It used to work and have been having problems when I looked at it today (Jan 7)... if you search for the similar hashtags in the instagram official apps, you will notice photos are missing there as well... lets hope instagram can fix this for us asap...

here is a link to my findings and i have sent it over to instagram developer bug reporter... [instagram media endpoint bug: only returns limited photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963545/instagram-media-endpoint-bug-only-returns-limited-photos)