# instagram media endpoint bug: only returns limited photos

Tags: api, instagram

tested this on media endpoint querying on different hashtags... only a few photos is returned from #artona (like 20 something) out of the 5000+ photos available. #iphone returns nothing right now.

this problem is not limited to this client.
i notice this problem on http://statigr.am/search/iphone where it too returns nothing for iPhone and a few photos for #artona... 
also tried the instagram iPhone app...
the number (limited) of photos returned are consistent between instagram clients so i suspect something is wrong with the api / instagram server.

Comment: That's all fine (well, not exactly *fine*), but what do you want us to do about it?  You would get further by posting this as a bug on Instagram's bug tracker, mailing list, or forum.

Comment: done that already. just want to share my findings here and respond to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947849/instagram-api-media-recent-shows-only-images-from-current-year/20963566#20963566

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hashtag `#iphone` and many others are blocked by Instagram so it returns error:

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"APINotAllowedError","code":400,"error_message":"This tag cannot be viewed"}}
```

http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/tags#iphone

As far as the hashtag not returning all results, Instagram posted on dev blog that they are having issues with hashtag API currently: http://developers.instagram.com/post/72497508869/platform-issues-with-hashtags